# How to connect masterdata and subreport in fastreport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have few problem about subreport in Fastreport. My problem is how to change standard format of report to subreport. In my design, there are group header band, masterdata band,detail band, and subdetail band (invisible in this screenshot) as attached below screenshot.

[image]

And I want to move detail-subdetail band (yellow remark) into subreport, and put in masterdata band. But after put subreport into masterdata band, I cant connect specific detail into masterdata band, the result is all detail band will be printed in masterband. Could somebody help me how to solve connecting masterdata band and subreport.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move Detail-Subdetail bands to subreport as Master-Detail bands